# SalesOrderList is returning "created_at" an hour late

Tags: sales-order

The problem is that when I invoke the field "created_at" is always an hour late and I don't know where can i change it.

Answer (score 0):

i think your server timezone is differently set,

Please check your timezone in php.ini file and set according to it.

it can be resolve your issue.

Thanks
Chirag

Comment: This sounds like the issue, also, daylight savings time (if applicable in your country).

Comment: @Chirag: Are you a M2 developer/specialist? Might have work for you.

Comment: Yes I am M2 certified professional developer , Thank you